# (JavaScript, Redux) Why are my nested array's getting deleted when returning, however when I don't return it doesn't?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

What I'm trying to do is take an array I am getting from an api, and cutting it down to smaller arrays of 4 elements maximum in each of the smaller arrays and store them in my redux store.

Here is how I'm calling the function:

```
const newArray = res.data.Search
let list = paginate(newArray)
console.log(list)
dispatch({ type: FETCH_SEARCH_SUCCESS, payload: list });
```

This is what I'm sending in the array:

```
[{Title: "The Avengers", Year: "2012"}, 
{Title: "Avengers: Infinity War", Year: "2018"}, 
{Title: "Avengers: Endgame", Year: "2019"}, 
{Title: "Avengers: Age of Ultron", Year: "2015"}, 
{Title: "The Avengers", Year: "1998"}, 
{Title: "The Avengers: Earth's Mightiest Heroes", Year: "2010–2012"},  
{Title: "Ultimate Avengers II", Year: "2006"}, 
{Title: "The Avengers", Year: "1961–1969"}, 
{Title: "Avengers Assemble", Year: "2012–2019"},
{Title: "Ultimate Avengers: The Movie", Year: "2006"}]
```

This is the code block for this problem:

```
const paginate = (arr) => {
  const mr = 4;
  let pn = 0;
  let results = []

  // calculate max number of pages user can go through (if its only 4 results or less it will just return the array as is)
  if(arr.length < mr){
    return arr
  }else {
    const maxPages = Math.ceil(arr.length/mr)
    // will make a nested array from every 4 indexes of arr, and put it inside of the results array
    for(let i = 0; i < maxPages; i++){
      results[i] = arr.slice(mr*pn, mr*pn+mr)
      pn+=1
    }
    console.log(results)
    //return results
  }
}
```

This is what is coming back in my console.logs when I dont use `return results`
[image]

And this is whats coming back when I do use the `return results`
[image]

Comment: Since its length`(3)` is less than `5` then it will go to `if block execution` and `return arr`

Comment: @SAM the length of array in the image is what happens when the function does it correctly, I am trying to paginate an array, and store it in my redux store.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the issue here lies withing the paginate function. I am guessing this is a rendering issue when you return the results you might be triggering the function to be called again with different argument maybe. I would suggest checking out what argument you are passing each time and what is the output. Could you provide some more info as to what are the arguments to recreate the issue?

```js
const paginate = (arr) => {
  const mr = 4;
  let pn = 0;
  let results = []

  // calculate max number of pages user can go through (if its only 4 results or less it will just return the array as is)
  if(arr.length < mr){
    return arr
  }else {
    const maxPages = Math.ceil(arr.length/mr)
    // will make a nested array from every 4 indexes of arr, and put it inside of the results array
    for(let i = 0; i < maxPages; i++){
      results[i] = arr.slice(mr*pn, mr*pn+mr)
      pn+=1
    }
    console.log(results)
    return results
  }
}

var x = paginate([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

Comment: I've edited the post so you can see how Im calling it